# Access Docker daemon Remote api on Docker for Mac

Tags: macos, docker

I'm runner Docker for OSX, and having trouble getting the Docker remote API to work.

My situation is this:

- Docker daemon running natively on OSX (https://www.docker.com/products/docker#/mac, so not the boot2docker variant)
- Jenkins running as docker image

No I want to use the Jenkins docker-build-step plugin to build a docker image, but I want it to use the docker daemon on the host machine, so in Jenkins settings, DOCKER_URL should be something like :2375. (Reason for this is I don't want to install docker on the jenkins container if I already have it on my host machine).

Is there a way to to this or is de Docker for Mac currently not supporting this? I tried fiddling with export DOCKER_OPTS or DOCKER_HOST options but still get a Connection refused on calling http://localhost:2375/images/json for example.

Basicly the question is more about enabling the Docker for OSX remote api, with use case calling it from a Jenkins docker container.

Comment: If I follow the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38293806 I get this error:Invalid bind address format: -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -H tcp://localhost:2376

Comment: What about sharing only Docker socket from host to container?

    jenkins:
      ...
      volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

Comment: This seems like a valid option, but now I get a Permission denied in stead of a connection refused. /var/run/docker.sock is a symlink to ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/s60, but even if I recreate the symlink as my own user I get the Permission denied error... `[INFO] I/O exception (java.io.IOException) caught when processing request to {}->unix://localhost:80: Permission denied`

Answer (score 36):

You could consider using socat. It solved my problem, which seem to be similar.

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:2375,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/docker.sock &
```

This allows you to access your macOS host Docker API from a Docker container using: `tcp://[host IP address]:2375`

On macOS socat can be installed like this:

```
brew install socat
```

See here for a long discussion on this topic: [Plugin: Docker fails to connect via unix:// on Mac OS X](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-153973)

Answer (score 0):

If you already added an SSH public key to your remote server, then you can use this ssh credentials for your docker connection, too. You don't need to configure the remote api on the server for this approach.

When connecting to macOS Docker Desktop, you could use ssh (after you have enabled it on Mac)

```
docker -H ssh:user@192.168.64.1 images
```

or

```
export DOCKER_HOST=ssh:user@192.168.64.1
docker images
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue but with mysql. I needed to expose the port of my docker hosts on port 43306 to docker image mysql running on port 3306.

**Solution**:

Create your docker image with -p parameter.

Example:

```
#> docker run -p 0.0.0.0:43306:3306 --name mysql-5.7.23xx -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=myrootdba -d mysql/mysql-server:5.7.23 --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Now I can connect from my host docker server on port 43306 to mysql docker image.