Access Docker engine API remotely on a Mac from a Windows client
I'm new to macOS and have installed Docker Desktop (4.37.1) on a Mac (macOS 15.2). Its Docker engine (27.4.0) should be accessed from a remote Windows client within the same LAN network.
I've read about a solution using socat:
Access Docker daemon Remote api on Docker for Mac
It's working so far but I still have two issues:

How can I make the docker engine always running ? Even after a reboot of the mac ?
How can I make the socat command be always running without manually starting ? Should be restarted automatically when the client is rebooted.

Nevertheless I'm still asking if there an easier or official way to get remote access without additional efforts of such scripts or commands ?

Try this method if you can : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68397544/2125671
